# write list of tuples of lists to text file

Tags: python, text, tuples

My result data is in a list of tuples, which each have a list in them:

```
[(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']),
 ...
 (['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'])]
```

What's the best way to strip all the nesting and quotes and write A:N to a tab delimited file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes are not part of the string, they denote the string. You would not be able to remove them.

The [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) makes this taks pretty straightforward:

```
import csv, itertools
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter="\t")
    writer.writerows(list(itertools.chain(*t)) for t in results)
```

This results in a file where each row corresponds to a tuple and a row contains the letters of both lists, separated by tabs.

Comment: Hmm it runs but outputs a blank file.. am I missing something else?

Comment: I updated the code. The problem was that the file was not closed yet by `csv.writer` and it also seems that the list was not generated properly... it should work now.

Answer (score -1):

Recursive is the natural way to solve this issue.

let target be your list [([A,B..]), ([A, B])]

```
def dump(target):
    for obj in target:
    if isinstance(obj,tuple) or isinstance(obj, list):
        dump(obj)
    else:
        print(obj),

dump(target)
print()
```